# Grouping Matrix rows based on Playa relationship field

Tags: matrix, playa, stash

I have my Field groups set up like so;

Trail

- title
- related_things [Playa]

Thing

- title
- content [Matrix]
- - content_text [Wygwam]
- - content_trail [Playa, assigns a Trail above]

When I edit a 'Thing', i'm adding multiple rows to the Matrix and assigning each {content_text} with a {content_trail}, which uses Playa:

[image].

However, some rows may have the same Trail assigned in the {content_trail}. This is not a problem, but in the template I would like the content displayed and grouped by the {content_trail}.

Here is my updated code using Stash;

```
{!-- Iterate over an array of unique Trails in the list --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="@:content_trail" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="33"}
    {!-- For each Trail output a data for the matching Trail --}
    {exp:stash:get_list name='@:content'
      orderby="content_trail"
      sort="desc"
     }
        {!-- This is the content_text column from the content Matrix table --}
        {stash:content_text}{content}{content_text}{/content}{/stash:content_text}
        {stash:content_trail}{exp:playa:children col="content_trail"}{title}{/exp:playa:children}{/stash:content_trail}
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:set_list}



{exp:stash:get_list name='@:content_trail' unique="yes"}
    {!-- Get the unique Trail title --}
    <h2>{content_trail}</h2>
    {!-- Get all content_text Matrix rows for this Trail --}
    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="@:content" prefix="result" orderby="total" match="#^{content_trail}$#" against="content_trail"}
        {content_text}
    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}

{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

What this is now doing is successfully getting the unique content_trail Playa data and displaying it all in one h2 tag like: Aviation TrailHeritage Trail, instead of creating two separate h2's. Also, it is not displaying the content_text rows that match the unique content_trail's.

Comment: Look at Stash Module (https://github.com/croxton/Stash). Will most likely help you do what you want. Here are the docs: https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki

Comment: Thanks Anna. I'm familiar with Stash and have used it extensively, but i'm still somewhat stuck on how to proceed.

Comment: If you do use Stash, you could do something similar to this: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/10127 but instead of 'distance' being unique in that example you would use iterate over 'content_trail'.

Comment: Thanks @Romans-8---31-39. I've added some updated code using the Stash example that gets me part way there, along with a new issue.

Comment: Instead of increasing parse depth in the first part and running playa, try setting all that before -- leaving you with only the {stash:content_trail}{your_already_set_stash_var}{/stash:content_trail} in your example. See how the first post set the first stash variable of 'distance' (Mark just recommended he combine his first 2 set lists into one). Confusing, but it looks like you're almost there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and messed around with what you had done so far, and you should be able to use the following to get started. It works when I tested it, but you'll of course need to put your own field names in. (Based on this support thread: ["Simulating 'group by' filtering and sorting."](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/stash/viewthread/10127))

```
{!-- ---------------------- 
ONE -  Grab all possible trails, and other variables needed.
---------------------- --}
{exp:stash:set_list 
    name="@:content" 
    parse_tags="yes" 
    parse_depth="1" 
    trim="yes"
}
    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="ch_programs"
        entry_id="{segment_3}"
        dynamic="no"
        status="not closed"
    }

        {!--   matrix   --}
        {YOUR_MATRIX_FIELD_NAME var_prefix="mx"}

            {!--   playa column   --}
            {stash:trail}
                {mx:YOUR_PLAYA_COLUMN_NAME var_prefix="pl"}
                    {pl:title}
                {/mx:YOUR_PLAYA_COLUMN_NAME}
            {/stash:trail}

            {!--   another column   --}
            {stash:second}{mx:A_SECOND_MATRIX_COLUMN}{/stash:second}
            {!--   ...continue adding any other matrix variables you will need to output later...   --}

        {/YOUR_MATRIX_FIELD_NAME}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}


{!-- ---------------------- 
TWO - Iterate over an array of unique Trails in the list.
---------------------- --}
{exp:stash:set_list name="@:content_trail" parse_tags="yes"}
    {exp:stash:get_list 
        name='@:content'
        orderby="trail"
        sort="desc"
     }
        {stash:trail}{trail}{/stash:trail}
    {/exp:stash:get_list}
{/exp:stash:set_list}


{!-- ---------------------- 
THREE - Output with formatting.
---------------------- --}
{exp:stash:get_list name='@:content_trail' unique="yes"}

    {!-- Get the unique Trail title --}
    <h2>{trail}</h2>

    {!-- Get all other Matrix data you've set that match this Trail --}
    {exp:stash:get_list:nested name="@:content" match="#^{trail}$#" against="trail"}

        {!--   ...output any other variables you have set with formatting...   --}
        <p>Second variable: {second}</p>
        <p>etc...</p>

    {/exp:stash:get_list:nested}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Comment: Genius. Thank you so much. Just need to be able to figure how to get the url_title from the playa field now and I'm done. :)

Comment: Hey @Romans-8---31-39. If I needed to get other data from the Playa relationship, how would i get that in this instance?